# Azure Batch : when we Disable a node do we get charged for the VM

Tags: azure-batch

In Azure Batch job there is an option to "Disable". When we do that do we still incur cost?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will still be charged. [Disabling a node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/disable-task-scheduling-on-a-node) merely disables job scheduling to the node; this is useful if you want to prevent scheduling to a node to diagnose issues.

You will need to delete the node to stop being charged.